# Get First line in Summernote

Tags: javascript, summernote

i can't get the first line of text using Summernote WYSIWYG Editor, i try using this code but not work. Always return all lines.

```
var t = $('.editor').code();
tmp = t.split("<br>");
var firstLine = tmp[0];
console.log(firstLine)
```

how could you do this?

Thx.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/help @BryGom

Comment: thank you for your quickly response.

Comment: ask the question again, or edit this one. Show us some code, and the things you have tried.